# Break down a string into an array/list bij alphabet and non-alphabet characters

Tags: arrays, regex, string, split, alphabet

I need to breakdown a string into an array or list of character sets based on the set beeing alphabet characters and non-alphabet characters.

For example:

string = -"Hello12$th'ere!@4"

the required result = [-"][Hello][12$][th]['][ere][!@4]

Does anyone have an idea of how to get to the required result? I was trying to achieve this by searching for a regex.split solution, but I can't find an expression that suits my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple regex does the trick: `([a-zA-Z]+|[^a-zA-Z]+)`

Test it out [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%7C%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5D%2B)&test_string=-%22Hello12%24th%27ere!%5E%404%22&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: Thanx a lot!! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: Are you sure? Check [`-"Hello12$th'ere!^@4"`](https://regex101.com/r/uA3aF3/1). Check [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926) and please fix your pattern.

Comment: It should be [a-zA-Z] og [a-z] and ignore case.

Comment: Will this work when the string ends in a run of letters?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for pointing that out. I missed the capital Z, wasn't paying attention :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex.Split with a pattern that looks for a border between a letter and a non-letter usung look-ariund expressions:

```
var t=Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[^a-zA-Z])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z])");
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/uSDliC)